# Excel file and key, value pair being send in postman using form-data. Empty data coming

Tags: postman, multipartform-data, form-data

[image]

File is getting recieved but site_list is not being fetched when i type `request.data.get('site_list')`. Can someone suggest a way to capture both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours of trying I figured out the solution.

So basically anytime we are sending more than one file/text Django automatically takes it as 'file' and shows everything under it. If you want to take the text/JSON, files separately then you have to create Model Forms.

I will post mine here.
Basically I wanted to accept an Excel File and Json text in the form-data and thats how i did it.

And this is how I sent my data from postman
[image]

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms    
class CustomerConfigUploadForm(forms.Form):
    files = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
    site_list = forms.CharField()
```

**views.py**

```
 def post(self, request, filename, format=None):
    try:
        form = VariableUploadForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
                  
        # Validate the form data
        if form.is_valid():

            # Reading the uploaded file content
            file_obj = request.data['files']
            file_content = file_obj.read()

            # Parsing the Excel file using pandas
            df = pd.read_excel(file_content, engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='test_sheet')
            
            #Getting Customer, Site, and User from Request
            site_list = request.data.get('site_list')

...rest whatever you want to do..
```